# how can i solve Telegram payload type error

Tags: telegram-bot, node-red

I am a newbe and have a problem when sending data to telegram . I get the error “msg.payload.type is empty”

my function code:

```
var temp = msg.payload + " °C";
msg.payload.type = “message”;
msg.payload.chatId = “xxxxxxxxxx”;
msg.payload.content = temp;
return msg;
```

[image: My flow attempt]

I managed to get it working by clicking on the inject node but that is not what i want, I want to send a message that is got with mqtt.  Mqtt doe work as I have it set up in a different flow

Comment: What exactly is in the inject node that "works"? We need more information

Comment: Is your "temp gauge" node passing a string, but the function is assuming it will get a msg?  Add a debug node and connect the output of "temp guage" to it.